# Execute celery task when worker is not running

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I want the celery task to be executed even when a celery worker is not present. That celery task should work like a normal function and get executed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options how to achieve this. The recommended approach explicitely queries workers for a list of registered tasks using [`broadcast`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Control.broadcast) control command:

```
app = Celery(broker='amqp://')

reply = app.control.broadcast('registered', reply=True)
tasks = set(t for n in reply for w in n.values() for t in w)

if 'my_task_name' in tasks:
    # there is an online worker that can handle the task
    # => use async mode
    app.send_task('my_task_name', args=(...), kwargs={...}, ...)
    # or use my_task.apply_async(...)
else:
    # there is no online worker for the task
    # => call the function directly
    my_task(...)
```

Alternatively, you could try to send the task directly to the broker and check the result after a short period of time. If the task still has a `PENDING` result after that time, presumably there's no worker that could handle the task. If that is the case, you can call the task as a normal function:

```
app = Celery(broker='amqp://', backend='rpc://')

result = app.send_task('my_task_name', args=(...), kwargs={...}, ..., expiration=5)
time.sleep(5)
if result.state == 'PENDING':
    # presumably the task didn't start because there hasn't been any worker
    my_task(...)
```

One has to be cautious with the second approach, though. There might be other reasons why a task is pending (e.g. they are busy and have prefetched the maximum number of tasks). Also, this example assumes that your broker supports AMQP expiration (e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-in-publishers)) and that you don't ignore the task result.